# Make android forget a jquery mobile page (back button issue)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

Android's back button is difficult to manage.

Here is a scenario :

```
 Main page => list of events
 Click on one item => see event
 Back button => return to the list
```

But. On my main page, I've got a search button. Here is the scenario :

```
 Main page => list of events in one city
 User clicks on search => User finds a city & clicks on city of interest
                          App goes back to main page using the city of interest
 User clicks on back => android goes back to search page
```

How can I ask Android to forget about the search page ?

On IOS, there's a back button on the search page if the user wants to go back without entering a city of interest, there's no back button on the main page (event if a city has been chosen).

Comment: you face this only on Android? using browser's back button?

Comment: Yes. On IOS, I "manage" a back button the way I want.